# Error in LaTeX Workshop switching from Docker to Podman

Tags: fedora, docker, latex, podman, visual-studio-code

## Starting point

I want to switch from Docker to Podman on my system. All the necessary packages from Docker were installed and I could use containers to turn my .tex files into a PDF easily and without a hassle. Since I use Fedora and Docker now has the same functionality as Podman (the latter is pre-installed - less bloatware), what could be a better idea than to switch. Too simple, as it turns out

## Things turning bad

However, when I uninstalled Docker, the LaTeX Workshop plugin no longer wanted to create a PDF because it couldn't find Docker. The following error message is displayed:

```bash
$ /home/$USER/.vscode-oss/extensions/james-yu.latex-workshop-9.8.2-universal/scripts/latexmk: line 2: docker: command not found.
```

Accordingly I have modified the `settings.json` in VS Codium to

```json
{
    "latex-workshop.docker.enabled": true,
    "latex-workshop.latex.outDir": "./out",
    "latex-workshop.synctex.afterBuild.enabled": true,
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "tab",
    "latex-workshop.docker.image.latex": "docker.io/texlive/texlive",
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "dev.containers.dockerPath": "podman",

}
```

I tried to `alias podman="docker"`, but it made no difference.

### My tech stack

- Podman 4.5.0
- LaTeX Workshop v9.8.2
- Dev Containers v0.290.0
- VS Codium 1.77.3 (rpm)
- Fedora 38
- fish instead of bash

Am I missing something? How do I get LaTex Workshop to recognize podman as a Docker replacement?